# How to find occupancy of bounding box in a grid?

Tags: python, c#, collision-detection, robotics, motion-planning

[occupancy grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wldz3.png)

Hi,i have a 4 point bounding box and a grid (x,y,resolution). How can I determine which cells will this bounding box occupy as seen in the above image?

Comment: You want a list of x, y cell coordinates?

Comment: yes, indices to be exact

Comment: You just have to loop through all the cells and check if they fall inside the rectangle. Plenty of algorithms available to do that.

Comment: Can you name a library or share the code?

Comment: A quick search gave this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/

Comment: thanks, i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) and iterated over grid for each cell to find occupied cells.